# Boot and driver issue

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2

HeyGuys

I've just installed ubuntu as my new OS but im facing some problems..Ive installed the latest version of ubuntu 22.04.2  the problem is tha after installation when i remove the media there was an error that it was showing me that i have to boot from the kernel first i watched some youtube videos and solved that problem... but now i get successfull boots with some error

So ive just restarted my pc and these errors message i am getting [After restart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIORd.jpg)

Regarding my hardware details  : [thi is network adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4DWA.jpg)im using a ethernet connection now but i have a wifi adapter plugged in too

Comment: If you've tried every possible solution, there is nothing we can do.

Comment: even not with the wifi driver

Comment: `but now i get successfull boots with some error message at first...` - What is the error message? `My wifi drivers are not showing in the additional drivers menu.` - Please edit and post your hardware details

Comment: Ive edited it plzz chk

Comment: I get the very same error message (VMX disabled by BIOS, etc etc) but it does not seem to affect anything.  I suspect it is just because of my old hardware.  Ubuntu works fine, so now I ignore the error and let the boot process proceed.  Hope your system works OK too.